# How do you set the timezone of the google calendar api?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am trying to use the get method to access events from google calendar. The url goes something like this:
`https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{Calendar ID}/events?singleEvents=true&key={API Key}`

How would i call the api and to pass in a timezone to have google adjust the dates/times according to the timezone that is passed in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify parameter called `timeZone` to url. You can add value like 'GMT+1:00' or 'UTC+1:00'.

> Time zone used in the response. Optional. The default is the time
>   zone of the calendar.
>
> Source: [Parameter for GET method.](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get#parameters)

[Try here with API explorer](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get#try-it)

Comment: No matter what value is specified all event times seem to be returned in the client timeZone?